# Printing out my Linked List prints out its memory location

Tags: c++

Okay, so I have to read in a file date.dat which stores a date and a corresponding time

eg.)

```
   12/2/13
   05:30
```

This is my code that reads it in:

```
void FillList(linkedList<myDate> &list)
{
  bool ok = true;
  int value;
  ifstream f;
  string fname;

  cout << "File: ";
  cin >> fname;
  f.open(fname.c_str());
  if (f.fail())
    {
      cout << "Failed to open" << endl;
      return;
    }

  myDate aDate;
  myTime aTime;
  f >> aDate;

  while (!f.eof())
    {
      f >> aTime;

      aDate.setTime(aTime);
      list.orderedInsert(aDate);
      cout<<aDate<<endl;
      f >> aDate;
    }

  f.close();

}
```

The code calls orderedInsert which inserts the date and time into a linkedList and puts it in order. OrderedInsert is here:

```
template <class T>
void linkedList<T>::orderedInsert(const T &value)
{
  current=head;

  while(current!=NULL && current->data < value)
    {
      trailCurrent=current;
      current=current->next;
    }
  if(current!=NULL)
    trailCurrent->data=new node(value,current);
  else
    head->data=new node(value,current);
}
```

I then want to print out the list which I do using:

```
void DisplayList(linkedList<myDate> list)
{
  cout << endl;
  cout << list;
}
```

But when I call DisplayList I am getting the memory location of each thing I want to print out instead of the Date and the Time. The memory location that prints out is like this:

```
     ======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00405000 r-xp 00000000 00:18 5508191                            /home/STUDENTS/jskoz233/prog4/app
00605000-00606000 rw-p 00005000 00:18 5508191                            /home/STUDENTS/jskoz233/prog4/app
01fbc000-01fdd000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
372ca00000-372ca20000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 4718921                        /lib64/ld-2.12.so
372cc1f000-372cc20000 r--p 0001f000 fd:00 4718921                        /lib64/ld-2.12.so
372cc20000-372cc21000 rw-p 00020000 fd:00 4718921                        /lib64/ld-2.12.so
```

any help? I have absolutely no clue. Thanks!

operator is :

```
template <class T>
ostream &operator<<(ostream &outStream,linkedList<T> list)
{
  T element;
  this.current=this.head;
  while(this.current!=NULL)
    {
      element=this.retrieve(element);
      outStream<<"["<<element<<"]"<<endl;
      this.current++;
    }
  return outStream;
}
```

copy constructor:

```
//Copy Constructor
template <class T>
linkedList<T>::linkedList(const linkedList &list)
{
  node *hurrah;
   hurrah=list.head;
delete this;
while(hurrah!=NULL)
  {
      orderedInsert(hurrah->data);
      hurrah=hurrah->next;
  }    
}
```

retriev:

```
//retrieve
template <class T>
bool linkedList<T>::retrieve(T &value) const
{
  if(current==NULL)
    return false;
  else
    {
      value=current->data;
      return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: you wrote `cout << list`, how is the corresponding `operator <<` implemented?

Comment: Unless my eyes are deceiving me, when did C++ ever have nested functions?  I am looking at your `orderedInsert` function -- it contains another function `FillList`.  Is this C++?

Comment: Pass your object `list` by const reference in the `operator <<`, not by value.  And since you passed it by value, did you implement a user-defined copy constructor for your linked list class?  Same thing with `DisplayList` -- you're passing by value, and that can only work correctly if you implemented a user-defined copy constructor.

Comment: The now would be a stellar time to step through your code in a debugger. And again, *what language is this?* because stuff like `this.current` is not valid Standard C++ *at all*.

Comment: @jskozerino `delete this`  What is this supposed to be doing in your copy constructor?  Also, doesn't this all boil down to what your `retrieve` function is actually doing?  That is where you ultimately get the data you are outputting.

Comment: But I am not using the retrieve function in my orderedInsert, should I be doing that?

Comment: @jskozerino I am focusing on the `operator <<` which produces the output.  In there, you are calling `retrieve` to get the value that you're placing in the stream.  Also, you should answer WhozCraig as to "what language is this?"  It looks like a weird mixture of Java and C++.

Comment: @jskozerino `element=this.retrieve(element)`  Do you see something wrong with that line, besides the bizarre `this.`?  You are assigning the return value of `retrieve` to element, and `retrieve` returns either `true` or `false`.  It should be this:  `this->retrieve(element);` with no assignment.  If this fixes your problem, I don't know what answer to give you, since you have a lot of weird and invalid C++ syntax being used in your function.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I actually did notice that and removed element like you said. I then make this->retrieve(element); and I am getting the same error, it is printing its memory

Comment: @jskozerino Start from the beginning.  First, without your linked list class, what happens when you simply use `myDate` with `cout`?  Did you check to make sure that the problem isn't something as basic as that?  Write a two line main program: `int main() { myDate d; cout << d;}`  Assuming that `d` in that small program contains something we can test, what gets outputtted?  Is it an address?  If so, then there is your problem.  As buggy as your list class may be, that wouldn't be the issue if you can't output a `myDate` correctly.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The problem isnt that I cant output myDate correctly because when I run FillList when it gets to cout<<aDate<<endl; it prints it out correctly from the file.

Comment: @jskozerino Well it's time to debug your code with the debugger.  I am looking directly at your output function, and that is exactly where you should be looking.  It is isolated to that one line of code I showed you.  `element=this.retrieve(element);   outStream<<"["<<element<<"]"<<endl;`There is no need to look anywhere else first besides there.  That is where you are ultimately getting your element to output, so that is where you must look first and debug.  I can't take your code since a) it isn't complete and b) it uses syntax that isn't C++.